# Slim PHP Framework Register System with mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, slim

I'm trying to make a register system using the Slim Framework and mySQL. Basically, I am just trying to POST data to the SQL database using a HTML form but it is not working.

I've tried using posting using the API and that works fine. Please help, it is for my Uni project. I'm also very new to the Slim Framework and PHP/API's in general.

Big Love.

MY HTML CODE: ---------------------------------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

        <form method="post" action="/api/customer/add"  data-ajax='false' id="from1">

            <label for="fname">First Name : <span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">

            <label for="lname">Last Name : <span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">

            <label for="email">Phone: <span>*</span></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="phone" placeholder="Email"/>

            <a  id="click" href="" class="ui-btn" data-theme="b" data-inline="true"> Submit</a>
            <a  id="showUsers" href="" class="ui-btn" data-theme="b" data-inline="true"> Show Users  </a>

        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

MY PHP CODE: ----------------------------------------------------

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->post('/api/customer/add', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $first_name = $request->getParam('first_name');
    $last_name = $request->getParam('last_name');
    $phone = $request->getParam('phone');


    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name,phone) VALUES 
    (:first_name,:last_name,:phone)";

    try{
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();

       $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);


        $stmt->execute();
        echo'{"notice": {"text": "Customer Added"}';
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the result? What does it say / do?

Comment: Nothing, i submit the form at the webpage refreshes. No data inserts into the SQL database

Comment: Your form has no submit button - it is just a link that redirects to the same page - your PHP script never gets executed. You either need to add convert it to an <input type="submit"> or get / write some javascript that will send the data to the script when the submit link is clicked. (or at least that's what I think without ahving tried it out)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but rather a means of **getting** to an answer. I've included if and else statements in there so you can know where the problem is exactly.

I don't know if this will affect it very much but I would also recommend moving **$first_name, $last_name, $phone** and **$sql** inside the try, catch.

I would also recommend making your button a submit button so this `<a  id="click" href="" class="ui-btn" data-theme="b" data-inline="true"> Submit</a>` turns to ` Submit

```
<?php
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

    $app = new \Slim\App;

    $app->post('/api/customer/add', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
        $first_name = $request->getParam('first_name');
        $last_name = $request->getParam('last_name');
        $phone = $request->getParam('phone');

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name,phone) VALUES (:first_name,:last_name,:phone)";

        try {
            $db = new db();
            if ($db = $db->connect()) {
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
                $stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name);
                $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    echo'{"notice": {"text": "Customer Added"}';
                } else {
                    echo "There was a problem adding customer.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "There was a problem connecting to the databse.";
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So you guys were right! It was basically my submit button wasn't submitting anything.

Plus my file path was wrong in terms of pointing to the API. (slimtest is my project name)

I changed the HTML form entirely.

I feel like Slim isn't covered a lot on here so ill show what i changed....

Here:

HTML code:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://slimtest/api/customer/add">

        <table>
           <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="first_name" class="textInput" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="last_name" class="textInput" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Surname:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="phone" class="textInput" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="register_btn" value="Register" class="buttonRegister"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>


    </form>
```

PHP Code didn't change however yes, a try catch would be good to see any errors thrown.

Thanks again guys :)